# Discconnected tables - filter

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix table which calculates dept cost for selected projects. To acheive this, I created two disconnected tables. I want to filter disconnected tables based on the country column (facts table) i.e if a country is selected, the disconnected tables which are used as slicers return the projects available in the selected country.

What I have done - I created two disconnected tables(Slicer_1 & Slicer_2).

**Slicer_1 = VALUES(Facts_table[project])
**

**Slicer_2 = VALUES(Facts_table[project])
**

I created the measures below for the selected projects.

cost_project1 = CALCULATE([cost_measure], FILTER(dim,dim[project] in {SELECTEDVALUE(Slicer_1[project])}))

cost_project2 = CALCULATE([cost_measure], FILTER(dim,dim[project] in {SELECTEDVALUE(Slicer_2[project])}))

What I am expecting - I want to add the country slicer so when a country is selected, Slicer_1 & Slicer_2 returns the projects in selected country. **The aim is to enable me compare costs between projects in the same location.** The challenge I have is that the country slicer has no interaction with the disconnected table slicers.

Please how do I acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

**1. Use a measure per slicer as a Visual Filter**

Create two new measures:

```
Slicer_1 count = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Facts_table'),
    'Facts_table'[project] = SELECTEDVALUE('Slicer_1'[project])
  )

Slicer_2 count = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Facts_table'),
    'Facts_table'[project] = SELECTEDVALUE('Slicer_2'[project])
  )
```

Then add each measure to their respective slicer as a Visual Filter, to either `is not blank` or `is greater than 0`.

**2. Include Country in your slicer tables and add Country relationship**

Update your slicers disconnected tables to:

```
Slicer_1 = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Facts_table'[project], 'Facts_table'[Country])
```

Then add relationship to your Country table.

Comment: Brilliant, please help mark answer as "accepted" for the benefit of all.